# Change data all row at 1 attribute in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I have 2 table have a cycle foreign key (1 --> 2 and 2 --> 1).
I want to insert data to table 1. But I can't insert all data at 1 time because of foreign key. So I set all data at that tribute is NULL. After that I set all data to table 2 easily. And now I want to change all NULL data at table 1.
And I don't know what to do because:

- INSERT only at new data to table
- UPDATE can't change 100 row at 1 tribute easily (Or I thinks that)

```
-- Create table 

CREATE TABLE TEACHER
(
    ID char(5) NOT NULL,
    Name char(30),
    Date date,
    Subject_ID char(5),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
CREATE TABLE SUBJECT
(
    Subject_ID char(5) NOT NULL,
    Name char(10),
    Dean_ID char(5),
    PRIMARY KEY (Subject_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Dean_ID)
    REFERENCES TEACHER(ID)
)
ALTER TABLE TEACHER
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_TEACGER_SUBJECT
FOREIGN KEY (Subject_ID)
REFERENCES SUBJECT(Subject_ID)

-- Insert data
INSERT INTO TEACHER
VALUES 
('001','A',1/1/1900,NULL),
('002','B',1/1/1900,NULL),
('003','C',1/1/1900,NULL),
('004','D',1/1/1900,NULL),
...;

INSERT INTO SUBJECT
VALUES 
('001','Math','002'),
('002','Chemistry','001'),
...

--Update foreign key in table TEACHER
???
```

I want to update NULL data to NOT NULL data in 100 row at foreign key.
I know I can set foreign key after insert but I want to know what code can help me.

Because my English is not good so forgive me if I said something wrong

Comment: please post suffient info for the two tables, i. E. column and foreign key definitions. In your example I see no reference from Table B to Table A.

Comment: thanks. I will edit right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I want to thank every answer here. That gives me a lot of useful information. I apologize for misinterpreting the UPDATE function, that making my search more difficult. And here will be the answer to my own difficulty:

```
UPDATE TEACHER
set Subject_ID = (case when ID = '001' OR ID = '009' then '002'
             when ID = '002' OR ID = '003' then '001'
             when ID = '004' OR ID = '006' then '003'
             when ID = '005' then '004'
             when ID = '007' OR ID ='008' OR ID ='010' then '005'
             .....
        end)
where ID IS NOT NULL
```

with that, I can replace NULL data easily like insert.

Answer (score 0):

In sql foreign key is primary key of some other table/relation..

and in table A its not foreign key it's Primary key first try to understand that first.

so in order to change Null constraint from the primary key of Table A

code:
Alter table A MODIFY 'Primary key column name' NOT NULL;

just write this code then it's fixed..

Comment: But I don't know how to modify many row at 1 attribute like insert

Answer (score 0):

If there can only be 1 subajct per teacher, you can `UPDATE JOIN`

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.Subject_ID = s.Subject_ID
FROM TEACHER t1 JOIN SUBJECT s ON s.Dean_ID = t1.[ID]
```

```
2 rows affected
```

```
SELECT * FROM Teacher
```

| ID | Name | Date | Subject_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | A | 1900-01-01 | 002 |
| 002 | B | 1900-01-01 | 001 |
| 003 | C | 1900-01-01 | *null* |
| 004 | D | 1900-01-01 | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7DNdXIAF)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm newbie so it'll help me a lot. But The teacher always has a subject to teach, not just a mean. So what I want is insert data to [Subject_ID] for table TEACHER

Comment: but how shall an algorithm know, which teacher ha which subject, when you want to automate the query like above, you need a bridge table for taht between reacher an subject, so that you, you need no column for that

Comment: I think I stated a lack of information, I have an external source of information. What I want is to input external information into the [subject_id] of TEACHER table. I show the SUBJECT table that there is a cycle relationship between them and I can't enter the subjectt_ID at the same time as the teacher's ID, I have to enter it later.